# How to type foreign currency symbols on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, keyboard, unicode

Is there a way to type special unicode characters, or more specifically foreign currency sumbols, on an iPhone or iPad?

I mean symbols like ¥ (Yen), ฿ (Bitcoin or Thai Baht), ₩ (Korean Won) etc.

I'm just using a normal english iOS 9. How can I type those e.g. when writing an email or Telegram message or when submitting info on a website?

Comment: I'm going to close this as a duplicate - but if you need help locating one specific item - please edit and @ping me and we can see about reversing the close/hold.

Comment: @bmike yes, in this case I'm actually curious about these specific symbols: ฿, ₩, and the letter ł ("L with stroke") for the Polish Zloty symbol "zł".

Comment: The Zloty is on the polish keyboard. I'll answer for all the currencies.

Answer (score 3):

You get all the currency symbols except the Baht for free on the US keyboard.

Press and hold the $ symbol and you'll see all the alternates.

To get the Baht symbol - add the thai keyboard and the Baht symbol will be added to the US keyboard. You don't need to switch to that keyboard - just add it. Similarly, you can use this answer to make shortcuts if you please for often used symbols if changing a keyboard is too long for your needs.

- [How can I insert symbols on iPad or iPhone?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1345/)